Query by ID returns many results
I perform search request by ID:
POST operation-test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "id": "aef07859-0ecb-46f5-9fa6-6633c0da00b8"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

But response contains 2 documents with different ids:
{
  "took": 15,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 2,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 29.047672,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "operation-test",
        "_id": "aef07859-0ecb-46f5-9fa6-6633c0da00b8",
        "_score": 29.047672,
        "_source": {
          "id": "aef07859-0ecb-46f5-9fa6-6633c0da00b8",
          "type": "PROCESS_INSTANCE_TERMINATE",
          "username": "ohHpqfq1",
          "createdAt": "2024-07-30T15:52:32.418329+03:00",
          "updatedAt": "2024-07-30T15:52:32.418345+03:00",
          "moduleIds": [],
          "totalCount": 396,
          "currentCount": 1
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "operation-test",
        "_id": "75387e4f-8598-46f5-9f0f-93003caaa9e3",
        "_score": 5.400874,
        "_source": {
          "id": "75387e4f-8598-46f5-9f0f-93003caaa9e3",
          "type": "PROCESS_SUSPEND",
          "username": "GR0fj4yu",
          "createdAt": "2024-07-29T17:33:25.976317+03:00",
          "updatedAt": "2024-07-29T17:33:25.97632+03:00",
          "moduleIds": [],
          "totalCount": 94,
          "currentCount": 1
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

How is it able?
